# Elasticsearch nodejs check if queue is full

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have the following error with elasticsearch

```
[remote_transport_exception] [es-0][x.x.x.x:9300][indices:data/write/bulk[s]]
```

Or

```
[remote_transport_exception] [es-0][x.x.x.x:9300][indices:data/write/bulk[s][p]]
```

It seems like it seems that the elasticsearch queue is full

I am using the nodejs lib `https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch` and this error occured after calling `client.index`.

I am using index as a promise into a rabbitmq consumer, the message are not coming more than 8 in the same time.

```
client.index().then(...)
```

It seems that the `then` is called when the update or create is still in queue, i tried to add `{wait_for_active_shards: 'all'}` but I have the same issue.

Comment: Were you able to find out if there is any method to find if queue is full?

Comment: No, just doing a retry

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue because the elasticsearch server was too busy.

I added a retry system in case of `429` error code, now it works fine